# spring boot @RequstBody convert blank string to zero of long

Tags: java, spring-boot

ajax send json like

```json
{
  "id":"123123"
  "parentId":"",
},
```

java class is:

```java
public class Page{
  private Long id;
  private Long parentId;
}
```

```json
as default, i get
{
  "id":123123
  "parentId":null
}
```

but i want parentId to be zero,
what should i do ?
thanks very much

Comment: `private long parentId` try it but not guarantee of success

Comment: You can assign default value for `parentId` as `0` in your Page object/DTO. Any issues there?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to initialise the default value, it will automatically assign that instead.

```
@JsonInclude(
  value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY,
  content = JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Page {
  private long id = 0;
  private long parentId = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If initializing the attribute in the `Page` class is not feasible or you also don't want to change the attribute from `Long` to `long` then you can implement a custom Jackson deserializer as follows:

```java
public class CustomLongDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Long> {

    @Override
    public Long deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String text = jp.getText();
        if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return Long.valueOf(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to configure its usage on the respective attribute:

```java
public class Page{
  private Long id;
  
  @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomLongDeserializer.class)
  private Long parentId;
}
```

Comment: thank you,but i can't trigger the CustomLongDeserializer,

Comment: What do you mean by "i can't trigger the CustomLongDeserializer"? Have you tried it and it does not work? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: thanks nice guy ,i solve it

Comment: Did you adapt anything to my suggestion? So that I can edit it and others benefit from it. Thanks!

Comment: i had Registered bean MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter,so @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomLongDeserializer.class) unreached, i need registerModule with CustomLongDeserializer for MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter